# Unwanted sound when notebook's screen is locked

Tags: laptop, audio, multiple-monitors, usb-c, device-manager

I have Legion 5 Pro 16ARH7H with Win 11 pro. Two external monitors are connected to my laptop, one is via HDMI and the other via VGA. Hence, the laptop has no VGA out; the second monitor is connected via Type C to the VGA/HDMI converter hub on the USB Type C-PD port of the laptop. A sound starts to come when my laptop goes to sleep or when the screen is locked. It is like connecting and disconnecting a new device on a USB port repeatedly.

I am an academician. When the screen is locked, that sound really disturbs me. Do you know how I can solve this problem?

The links to the products are below.

Best Regards,

The notebook: https://psref.lenovo.com/Detail/Legion/Legion_5_Pro_16ARH7H?M=82RG0097TX

The hub: https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32840117001.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2tur

or

https://www.teknostore.com/ugreen-type-c-vga-hdmi-donusturucu-adaptor-439?utm_source=ugreenturkiye&utm_medium=urunsayfasi&utm_campaign=aciklama

Comment: `I am an academician` I'm just a regular magician

Answer (score 1):

Since one monitor relies on using a USB port, the issue is likely that USB power saving is enabled. When the PC is locked or suspended, the USB port loses power if selected suspend is enabled in Power Options.

Open the [Advanced Power Options](https://geekflare.com/windows-power-options/) settings and disable *USB selective suspend setting* when plugged in, and possibly on battery, depending on your usage.

[image: Disable USB power off]